# Embeding spreadsheet into ASP.NET MVC 3 page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, excel, graph

I have a project coming up and I am not sure what technologies to use. I am adding functionality to a web application which shows user statistics for our company websites. For example number of loggings and page visits.

What I would like to do is somehow have a spreadsheet embeded into the page and a choice of graphs connected to the data. My reasoning is that the spreadsheet on the page is dynamic and they can filter their data and display one of several graphs.

It would be a nice to have if the user can export the data to excel. This isn't as difficult because I can build this when they post to the server.

To summarise I am trying to

- Create a spreadsheet control in MVC 3. This is related to a graph, it will change when the spreadsheet is filtered.
- It can be either JS library or C#
- Should be able to export the data to a excel

Anyone have suggestions of a good way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you thing about: [Excel Interactive View](http://www.excelmashup.com/). It is good because you only create simple table on your website. Rest is done by Microsoft :) I used this in two projects and users were very happy, because thay use it like excel, and they can easy download modified excel.

Comment: I have looked at the link you provided and it says you have to host the spreadsheet using skydrive or sharepoint. Is there no other way of doing this?

Comment: But basic access will be without skydrive or sharepoint. Just create html table and use this procedure: http://www.excelmashup.com/EIV/AddButton

Comment: I will explore this more and see if it is suitable. Thanks!